# Contact Form 7 - How Do I Style The Select Arrow and Select Options

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm building a website using **Contact Form 7** for WordPress and am having issues styling the select menu. Specifically, I cannot move the arrows or add padding to the dropdown so it's not so tight.

I've tried using this CSS to add spacing to the dropdown items *(and some other CSS trickery)* but it has no effect:

```
options {
 padding: 20px 10px!important;
 margin: 20px 10px!important;
 line-height: 36px!important;
 border-bottom: 10px solid tan!important;
}
```

Do you know if there's a way to control the styling behavior of CF7's select menu *(arrow and options dropdown)*?

Thank you!

**Demo Website:**
https://miles.birdhouse-demos.com/connect/

[image: Cannot Move or Find Arrow]
[image: Cannot Add Space]

Answer (score 3):

Try this

It's possible to customize the dropdown arrow with this code:

```
select {

  -webkit-appearance: none;

  -moz-appearance: none;

  background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png);

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-position-x: 98%;

  background-position-y: 2px;

}
```

Here is a list about what you can do with this code:

- Remove completely the arrow, to do so, simply remove this line: "background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png);"
- Customize the arrow size. You need to add the following line to the code given above: background-size: 30px 30px;

You can change the value in px.

- Change the arrow, to do so, replace the URL in the following line of code: "background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png);"

This guide will help you to inject the code: https://www.jotform.com/help/117-How-to-Inject-Custom-CSS-Codes

If you have any questions, let me know.

Thanks.

Credit: Kevin - From: https://www.jotform.com/answers/2449062-how-can-i-remove-modify-change-the-dropdown-arrow-using-css

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31983560)

Comment: This works well for me. Easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

CSS styling for `<select/>` fields is very limited and does not allow you to achieve this.  You will need to use a hybrid field plugin that constructs dropdowns with HTML lists that can be styled, such the [Hybrid HTML Dropdown](https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/) plugin, which can be [styled](https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/styling/) and can be loaded on your page to [convert](https://aurovrata.github.io/hybrid-html-dropdown/examples/#visual-styling-change-to-reflect-field-update) your existing `<select/>` fields into hybrid ones,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    let sel, hyd;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {  //instantiate on document ready.
      sel= document.querySelector('#my-select-list');
      hyd = new HybridDropdown(sel,{});
    })
  })
 </script>
```

Alternatively, you can install the Smart Grid-layout [extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) for CF7 which has a dynamic-dropdown field tag you can use instead of the CF7's default dropdown, and has as the option to display as a Hybrid Dropdown field for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use that way:

```
span select {
    width: 100%;
    background: url('/path-of-your-icon.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 60% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 1.4rem;
}
```